# Callback function doesn't exectute

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

So, I have two functions and I would like the second one to execute only after the first one has finished.

This is the case:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  function myLoopOne () {      
    console.log('first function executed');
  }

  function myLoop () {          
    console.log('second function executed');
  }

  myLoopOne(function(){
    myLoop();
  });

});
```

Unfortunately, only the first function executes and the callback function myLoop() doesn't get called.

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And where do you call the callback? You pass the function as a parameter to myLoopOne but the code is missing the execution part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the reference of the function you provide to `myLoopOne()` and call it, like this:

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function myLoopOne(callback) { // < receive the function reference
    console.log('first function executed');
    callback && callback(); // < call the referenced function, if one was provided
  }

  function myLoop() {
    console.log('second function executed');
  }

  myLoopOne(function() {
    myLoop();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link">Click me</button>
```

Note that this pattern only applies to asynchronous code. It's redundant if you're working synchronously.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Need to add callback as a parameter and method call inside the function which call another function. Not only a callback , you can pass any word as a parameter and method call.

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myLoopOne(myLoop);
});

// need to add callback as a parameter and method call inside the function which call another function
function myLoopOne(callback) {
  console.log('first function executed');
  callback();
}

function myLoop() {
  console.log('second function executed');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="link">Click me</button>
```